# Error in socket.io connection - 'Session ID unknown'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, socket.io, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an "**Elastic Beanstalk**" environment with the scalable server running 2 Ec2 instances.

On my root, I am serving angular 7 content using PHP API (using Codeigniter from API folder). I have **socket.io** chat module in my Node folder.

I am using **Nginx** to set up the Node and PHP project in a single EB environment.

I tried different options by modifying my Nginx **.conf** file as per some research but not able to fix the issue.

Here my Nginx **.CONF** setting file for **SOCKET.IO**.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.domain.com;
    root   /var/app/current/node;
    location / {
      proxy_pass            http://127.0.0.1:3000;
      proxy_read_timeout    3600;
      proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
      proxy_redirect        off;
      proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Port 443;
      proxy_set_header      Host $host;
    }   
}
```

My **socket.io** code.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = 3000;

var socketController = require('./socketController.js')

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
var nsp = io.of('/namespace');
/**
 * Socket for chat message
 */
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('client_user_join', socketController.userJoin.bind(null, socket, nsp, io));
    socket.on('client_send_chat_message', socketController.sendChatMessage.bind(null, socket, nsp, io));
    socket.on('client_received_chat_message', socketController.receivedChatMessage.bind(null, socket, nsp, io));    
    socket.on('disconnect', socketController.disconnect.bind(null, socket));
});

http.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

I am getting `Session ID unknown` at intial lever and after few minutes I am getting **failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400**

My socket connection link

```
https://sub.domain.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mtzwcpj&sid=TSMAaNI0KxDuzcIEAA4s
```

I already try following option.

Try to connect socket server using different transports.
 `this.socket = io('https://sub.domain.com/namespace', {transports: ['websocket']});`

At the AWS side, enable **Stickiness** to 1 day.

I do not understand whether it blocking by Nginx configuration or I have to use Radis to fix this as I have two EC2 instances running.

Comment: Without reading much, the nginx config i use has `proxy_http_version 1.1;`

Comment: @RolandStarke I tried that option also but no luck.

Comment: Does it work local? `var nsp = io.of('/namespace');` seems a bit strange as you dont use the variable. but i guess thats just for this question.

Comment: Yes it works on local as I do not have a different server on local nor Nginx

Comment: Do non websocket requests work e.g. `app.get('/',` (So accessing `https://sub.domain.com/` serves the `__dirname + '/index.html'` file?) And https is handled somewhere else?

Comment: Yes. It works. Subdomain successful load that file so no issue with routing and nameserver

Comment: subdomain successfully loading my index file but socket connection also give same error from an index file

Comment: See my index.html file. I am using this file to test messaging and connection. https://www.screencast.com/t/WBHla6HF